# Is it bad practice passing all props as an object with spread operator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Usually I pass props to my components/HTML tags as follow:
`<div style={{ marginLeft: '1rem' }} id={myIdConst} />`

But recently I was reading some examples from TanStack table and encountered this:

```
<th
  {...{
    key: header.id,
    colSpan: header.colSpan,
    style: {
      width: header.getSize(),
    },
  }}
> ... </th>
```

Here, props are passed as a object with the spread operator.
When this code is transpiled to javascript code, it will be the same as the usual way of passing props.
To me, it seems more readable and easier to write, specially when a prop is an object (like style, the usual way would be `style={{prop: 'value'}}`, here would be `...{style: {prop: 'value'}}`)

But I never saw this at any other place. Why is it? Is it a bad practice?

Comment: There's no point in using the spread syntax with an object literal being spread. It actually add two extra lines to your code. There's not that much of a difference between `…: …,` and `…={…}` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a preference. Which you are more comfortable with is the better one.

I guess it is done with the spread operator only to avoid `={}` in the props